# Error in java code for merge sort

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, merge

Merge Sort is not a new algorithm and there are solutions available to it. I was trying to write my own code but it has some logical errors. 
Any insights about what i am doing wrong?

```
public class MergeSort {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {5,4,8,3,7,10};
        mergeSort(array);
        System.out.println("Sorted array: \n");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(array[i]);
        }
    }

    public static void mergeSort(int[] array) {
        if (array.length > 1) {
            int[] firstHalf = new int[array.length / 2];
            System.arraycopy(array, 0, firstHalf, 0, array.length / 2);
            mergeSort(firstHalf);

            int[] secondHalf = new int[array.length - array.length/2];
            System.arraycopy(array, array.length / 2, secondHalf, 0, array.length - array.length/2);
            mergeSort(secondHalf);

            merge(firstHalf, secondHalf, array);

        }
    }

    public static void merge(int[] firstHalf, int[] secondHalf, int[] array) {
        int i = 0;
        int j = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
            for (i = 0, j = 0; i < firstHalf.length && j < secondHalf.length; i++, j++) {
                if (firstHalf[i] < secondHalf[j]) {
                    array[k] = firstHalf[i];
                    i++;

                } else if (secondHalf[j] < firstHalf[i]) {
                    array[k] = secondHalf[j];
                    j++;

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `but it has some logical errors.` Please elaborate. What is it doing wrong? Give an example input that fails, and the failing output. If you have run time errors - give the complete stacktrace. If it does not compile, tell us where.

Comment: Without the above details. this question is off topic: `Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple issues with your merge() function:

- The most obvious one, `merge()` does not need a nested loop.  Note
  that you    repeatidly overriding values of `array[k]` with new
  values.
- Another issue is at each iteration of the inner loop you increase one
  of `i` or `j` twice.
- In addition, there are some elements that you never touch, the biggest elements in one of the arrays (consider if you have an already sorted array, so you have `left=[1,2,3] right=[4,5,6]`. After you figure out you need to increase only one iterator, and not both, you will still have an issue that you never touch the elements `2,3` from `left`).

My tip: Try to follow a step by step pseudo code when implementing the algorithm for the first time. If you feel you got it, erase it and try writing it again, without the reference.

Comment: Thank you! Yours suggestions are so apt. keep up the good job!